# How to access an element from a list of lists in python networkX? TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension, networkx

I have an output from my  loop, where G is a Graph from networkX.

```
for node in G.nodes():
    start_end = [(node,k) for k,v in nx.shortest_path_length(G, node).items() if v == d]
    print (start_end)
```

which is lots of list classes with tuples inside  them.
(if it was just one list, it would be easy to do start_end[0][0].)

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
....
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[('45', '27'), ('45', '26'), ('45', '39'), ('45', '24'), ('45', '81'), ('45', '29'), ('45', '46'), ('45', '51'), ('45', '23'), ('45', '8'), ('45', '60'), ('45', '83'), ('45', '86'), ('45', '149'), ('45', '18'),  ('45', '99'), ('45', '78'), ('45', '120'), ('45', '134'), ('45', '121'), ('45', '122')]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[('129', '134')]
[]
[('134', '92'), ('134', '97')]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

I want to grab the first element of the longest list  '45' , in this example.
I have tried to sort the lists by length.

```
sorted(start_end, reverse=True)
max(start_end)
```

which yields an error

```
#TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I have also tried

```
start_end = len([(node,k) for k,v in nx.shortest_path_length(G_sc, node).items() if v == d])
print(max(current))
```

with the same error.

Below is the  pseudo-code that you can reproduce.
here, how can I access the tuple ((2, 1) from the second (longest) list?

```
In: 
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2); G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(3,1); G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(2,3); G.add_edge(4,3)

for node in G.nodes():
    start_end_nodes = [(node, k) for k,v in nx.shortest_path_length(G, 
                      node).items() if v == 2]
    
    print(start_end_nodes)

Out:
[(1, 3)]
[(2, 1), (2, 4)]
[(4, 1)]
[(3, 2)]
```

Comment: You may want to check what `nx.shortest_path_length(G, node)` and its `items()` return.

Comment: dict_items([tuple,tuple,tuple..])?                  TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable

Comment: it looks like a sort by length problem, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this issue is to store all the `start_end` values in a list - `start_ends` - and then getting the max based on `len`:

```
max(start_ends, key=len)
```

### *full code*

```
def f2(G):
    start_ends = []
    d = 2
    for node in G.nodes():
        start_end = [(node, k) for k,v in nx.shortest_path_length(G, node).items() if v == d]
        start_ends.append(start_end)
        
    #print(max(start_ends, key=len)[0])
    return max(start_ends, key=len)[0]
```

#### For your graph:

```py
#In:
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2); G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(3,1); G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(2,3); G.add_edge(4,3)

f2(G)

#Out:
(2, 1)
```

#### Option 2:

You could also use `sorted` for the same effect but I'd recommend using it if you want the list sorted and not just the max.

```
# to sort use:
start_ends_sorted = sorted(start_ends, key=len, reverse=True)

# to get the same result as before:
start_ends_max = start_ends_sorted[0][0]

# ---------------
# In your example:
start_ends_sorted = [[(2, 1), (2, 4)],
                     [(1, 3)],
                     [(4, 1)],
                     [(3, 2)]]
start_ends_max = (2, 1)
```

Comment: thank you, willcrack. somebody downvoted my question, yet I'm only learning this on a coursera course. I have asked on here because students are not allowed to post any code solutions on their forums!

Comment: and yes, I'll mark it as an accepted answer : )

Answer (score 0):

somebody suggested this version to me by creating an empty dictionary.
so I'm trying to understand how this works, more specifically, the line 'scores[node] = end_node, and if its better(faster) than yours.

```
def f2(G):        
    scores = {}
    d = 2
            
    for node in G.nodes():
        shortest = nx.shortest_path_length(G_sc, node)
        end_node = len([k for k,v in shortest.items() if v == d])
        scores[node] = end_node
    return ((max(scores))
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately this solution will return `4` instead of `(2,1)` since `4` is *the highest node label*. If you want to get the `start_node` label(`2`) change `return ((max(scores))` to `return max(scores, key=lambda k: scores[k])`. This solution appears to be slightly faster: [On 7 runs: `1.04 s vs. 1.06 s` for a 1000 node Barabasi-Albert graph]